# How do I create a custom hyperlink functionality in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hyperlink

I would like to know how to create and implement a custom hyperlink in the Eclipse UI - I do not want to make a complete custom editor, if at all possible - just add to my current ability to ctrl+click on an series of characters and automatically navigate straight to a matching reference.

I am not incredibly familiar with making Eclipse plugins, but I'm guessing that will be required.

I am good with regular expressions, if that helps.

I imagine it would be possible with some sort of declarative syntax (text that matches this pattern links to any lines that look like this in these files, or something)

Two of the things I've wanted to do are find a jsp file based upon a function that returns a string that matches one of those jsp files OR find one or more JavaScript functions in source code that use a particular name (these seem like they might be more complex than a declarative syntax would support)

If there are already one or more plugins that allow me to declare a "rule" like that, that would also work, but one or more tutorials on the topic would be excellent - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to implement a [hyperlink detector](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_hyperlinkDetectors.html). You have to create an Eclipse plugin, which implements that extension point. The "class" attribute of that extension point needs to point to a class which implements [IHyperlinkDetector](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/hyperlink/IHyperlinkDetector.html). Your best bet is probably to extend the [AbstractHyperlinkDetector](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/hyperlink/AbstractHyperlinkDetector.html).

There is also a [small tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-ecl-commplgin3/section3.html) by IBM. Be careful, it is from 2006, there might have been minor API changes since then.

Comment: Thanks - I've seen all of those, thanks to Google :-D. The first three would no doubt be helpful reminders if I even had a clue where to start, and though the IBM tutorial may be my best bet at this point, it does seem to be geared for creating an entire Eclipse UI - I want to use all the formatting and hyperlinking that I'm used to but add a few types/rules - I'll have to dig into it and see if I can pull out the pieces I need (?)

Comment: Is there anyother tutuorils

Answer (score 1):

For who finds this just like I did but still didn't get it to work:

When working with extension points to define `HyperlinkDetectors` for your `CustomTextEditor` be sure to have your `CustomSourceViewerConfiguration` extend `TextSourceViewerConfiguration`, not just `SourceViewerConfiguration`.

Because this is the class that contains the call to the registry with `HyperlinkDetectors` configured via the extension point.
To activate them this class needs an `IPreferenceStore` so you must also initialize your `CustomSourceViewerConfiguration` with an `IPreferenceStore` in the constructor and call `super(iPrefStore);`

Answer (score 0):

The maarten's answer is partially correct, but you also need to override `getHyperlinkDetectorTargets()` method of your `TextSourceViewerConfiguration` child (`CustomSourceViewerConfiguration` in the maarten's case). Something like that:

```java
@Override
protected Map<String, IAdaptable> getHyperlinkDetectorTargets(
    ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
    Map<String, IAdaptable> targets = 
        super.getHyperlinkDetectorTargets(sourceViewer);
        targets.put("editortest.editors.MyEditor", edit); 
        return targets;
    }
```

`editortest.editors.MyEditor` here is an ID of the target defined in `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectorTargets`. This solution works with the newest Eclipse Oxygen.